# Balancing reading and college responsibilities

Tags: books, reading

My exams start in three weeks. In three weeks I will reach all the planned obligations, but I have one problem. I bought a book that I wanted to read for a long time. The book has a large number of pages, and I have to start studying for exams, so I would have to balance reading and studying. That might work, but I used to have an approach to books where I read the exam books and the books I chose separately. I am afraid that my literature will get mixed up and that I will not understand well the two different contents. How did you balance reading with schoolwork? Did you read books during the exam period?

Comment: I was in Electrical Engineering (EE) so there's little danger in conflating the material with study material, but if your major is say English lit, you would possibly do so!  If this is not a problem, you can take small breaks to read, but I would focus on studying.

Comment: Hi. Would you consider editing your post to add a few clarifications? Pretend as if we don't know anything about what you're studying, what year you're in and how university works in your region of the world. Pretend we don't know what are "planned obligations", we don't know whether the book you want to read is related to your studies or not, we don't know whether it's a novel or an essay or a textbook; pretend we don't know how large is a "large number of pages"; etc. Pretend we don't even know what's an exam book: is it a book with exercises, or with lessons, or with past papers?

Comment: What kind of book?

Comment: I am studying at the Faculty of Law, and soon I will have exams in the subjects of philosophy of law and international procedural law. The book I want to read is The Downfall of the West by Oswald Spengler.

Comment: It seems that you seek a compilation of examples in hope for someone to offer a recipe that mediates between your desire (read a literature book) and your need (study for exams). We could substitute chocolate cake versus cardio exercise, and we'd be at the same quandary but in the StackExchange for Eating Habits. Improve your question please by tempering your general request for examples of how folks handle their battles of wants versus needs and by focusing on something with stronger relevance to an academia-oriented question *sans* the physiological underpinnings.